# Contagem de elementos filhos retorna 'Undefined' no jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

Estou tentando fazer a contagem de elementos filhos de um elemento pai com jQuery no HTML que criei, mas está retornando o valor 'Undefined'.

```
<div class='dataGrid'>
    <div class='dataGrid-item'></div>
    <div class='dataGrid-item'></div>
    <div class='dataGrid-item'></div>
    <div class='dataGrid-item'></div>
    <div class='dataGrid-item'></div>
    <div class='dataGrid-item'></div>
</div>
```

E o jQuery que incrementei foi.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready({
        var qtdGrid = $('div.dataGrid div.dataGrid-item').lenght;
        window.alert(qtdGrid);
    });
</script>
```

No console nenhum erro é retornado, somente no alert o 'Undefined'.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você colocou `lenght` ao invés de `length`

```js
/// var qtdGrid = $('div.dataGrid div.dataGrid-item').lenght;
///                                                     ^

console.log( [1,2,3,4].length );
///                      ^ exemplo
```

Comment: puts que feio, rsrsrs obrigado. Excluo a pergunta?

Comment: Pode excluir se quiser, pois acaba caindo como erro de digitação =)

Comment: Não deu pra excluir, até deu mais trampo fazer o post que o código HTML jkkkkkkk. "Você não pode remover esta pergunta, pois outros usuários investiram tempo e esforço para respondê-la. Para obter mais informações, [1]visite a central de ajuda[2]"

Comment: @EliseuB. é só votar para excluir que a comunidade se encarrega do resto. ;)